# How to call async function before other functions

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs

I have a funtion for deleting reports, here is my code

```
public deleteCustomReport(dataItem): void {
      var scheduleNames = this.getScheduleNames(dataItem.id);      

      this.confirmDelete(scheduleNames, dataItem);
    }
```

Function `this.getScheduleNames(dataItem.id)` is async function and I need to call it before `this.confirmDelete(scheduleNames, dataItem)` for my code to work. Right now it calls `this.getScheduleNames(dataItem.id)` after `this.confirmDelete(scheduleNames, dataItem)` and `var scheduleNames` is left undefind.

Here is my code for `this.confirmDelete(scheduleNames, dataItem)` function

```
private confirmDelete(scheduleNames, dataItem): void {

      var confirmDeletion = angular.copy(this.constantService.confirmDeleteSwalSettings);

      if (scheduleNames != null) {
        confirmDeletion.text = "Are you sure you want to delete " + dataItem.name + " report?";
      }
      else {
        confirmDeletion.text = "This report is in schedual. Are you sure you want to delete " + dataItem.name + " report?";
      }

      this.sweetAlert.swal(confirmDeletion, (isConfirm) => {
        if (isConfirm) {
          this.reportsService.deleteCustomReport(dataItem.id)
            .then(data => {
              this.getReports();
            });
        }
      });
    }
```

and for `this.getScheduleNames(dataItem.id)`

```
private getScheduleNames(id): string {
      var name = "";

      this.reportsService.checkIfReportIsInSchedule(id)
        .then(data => {
          name = data;
        });

      return name;
    }
```

Comment: `this.getScheduleNames(dataItem.id).then(function(scheduleNames) { this.confirmDelete(scheduleNames, dataItem); }`

Comment: `private getScheduleNames(id): Promise<string> { return this.reportsService.checkIfReportIsInSchedule(id); }`

Comment: Sorry but neither of your answers worked for me